# Why is Node.js response JSON displayed in raw form in Slack?

Tags: node.js, json, slack

I am sending a JSON response from Node.js server to a Slack App.
This response is displayed in raw form, as JSON, instead of being formatted properly.

Minimum code that replicates the problem:
**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// POST request processing
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var arr1 = [{"type":"section","text":{"type":"mrkdwn","text":"*Lorem Ipsum*"}},
    {"type":"section","text":{"type":"mrkdwn","text":"_Lorem Ipsum_"}},
    {"type":"section","text":{"type":"mrkdwn","text":"`Lorem Ipsum`"}}]
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json(arr1);  
});

// Listen to the AppEngine/Heroku - specified port, or 8080 otherwise
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port ${PORT}...');
});
```

The JSON message should be rendered like visible here:
[api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22*Lorem%20Ipsum*%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22_Lorem%20Ipsum_%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%60Lorem%20Ipsum%60%22%7D%7D%5D)

[image]

Instead, it is displayed like this:

[image]

I have also tried this and numerous other ways:

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

I've found this [proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express) on SO, and looked through Slack and Node.js documentation. I've advanced quite far in my app, but responses are still not rendered properly, so I figured I would ask here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the appropriate [SDK](https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack bot doesn't interpret json message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132115/slack-bot-doesnt-interpret-json-message)

Answer (score 0):

please use a simple express response `res.send(your JSON object);`